# adding minutes using a formatted string in java or joda time

Tags: java, string, datetime, jodatime

I'm trying to add a string representation of time in minutes (4:30) to another string (10:00:00) like you would say 'ten o'clock plus 4 minutes, 30 seconds.

If I sound a bit verbose, it's because I've spent 7 hrs searching the web for an answer and keep getting how to convert a fixed string of even minutes to date/time.

I tried to use joda time but can't figure out how to make 4:30 into an integer (I can make it work with'04'). These times are strings in code from variables, not something the user enters at the command line.
I'm using JDK 1.7 and netbeans 8.

Comment: so the output should be 10:04:30 ? or exactly like you said in the first sentence ten o'clock plus 4 minutes, 30 seconds?

Comment: 10:04:30 for the output.

Comment: An exact answer using an alternative library (not Joda-Time) see https://gist.github.com/MenoData/6c6924f274fd0da5417c But of course, for this simple use-case changing/using another library is probably overkill, the suggestion of @MadProgrammer related to Joda-Time works, too (with some refinements for the output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Java 8 Time API

You could take advantage of Java 8's new Time API, which is similar to JodaTime

The first thing you need is a `Duration`, something like...

```
Duration d = Duration.parse("PT0H4M30S");
```

or

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes(4).plusSeconds(30);
```

Next, you need to generate a `LocalTime` value

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("10:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
```

and then you can simply add the `Duration` to it

```
time = time.plus(d);
```

which will result in a value of

```
10:04:30
```

The difficult part is getting the values of the duration from the `String`, but if you can guarantee the format, you could simply use `String#split`

## JodaTime

JodaTime would make it slightly easier, for example, you can parse `4:30` into a `Period` using something like...

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(":")
        .appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();
Period p = formatter.parsePeriod("4:30");
```

Then you could simply parse `10:00:00` into a `LocalTime` and add the `Period`

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("10:00:00", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
lt = lt.plus(p);
System.out.println(lt);
```

which outputs...

```
10:04:30.000
```

Comment: @MP, thanks I'll try your joda time example tomorrow. I'll need to lose the '.000' on the output. I can't use Java 8, it's a db app using Access.

Comment: @PhilLongenecker The `.000` is just `LocalTime`'s `toString` method output, you would, like all other questions about date/time formatting, use a `DateTimeFormatter` to produce a `String` representation of the `LocalTime` in the format you want. I assume you're using the jdbc:odbc bridge then?  Maybe you should investigate one of the jdbc drivers for Access

Comment: My upvote but you should format the result using the same formatter according to the requirements of OP (suppressing the millisecond part).

Comment: @MenoHochschild As I said to the OP, the output is only the result of `LocalTime`'s `toString` method, as with all questions related to date/time formating, the OP should use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the object to the desired output. As far as I can read, the question doesn't have a desired output format

Comment: @MP It works great, many thanks (and to all SO'ers). I was able to change the fixed times in your example to get the text of the variables (ie format, start(clock) time, and length), format the result as needed and display in a textField. Now I'm on to finding if an elapsed time is greater/less than a reference time then I'm good with using Time for the rest of my app. As far as using other jdbc drivers, the odbc driver turns out to be fastest with embedded database like Access. Someday somebody will figure out a new odbc driver for J8 ;-) Marked as accepted.

Comment: @MenoHochschild His answer made me figure out the format I wanted, which was not hard and a good exercise (that I needed to do on my own). I learn more by success, but a few failures along the way give me more ideas to work with. Which is always a good thing. And why I come to SO looking for answers quite a lot. So, no harm done.